# Direct limit; what is the conditions for canonical homomorphism to be surjective

Tags: category-theory, modules

I am studying directed system and direct limit. Consider a directed system $(A_{i},\alpha_{i})$, where $A_{i}$ is a sequence of modules(or algebras, groups,etc). $\alpha_{i}:A_{i}\rightarrow A_{i+1}$ be homomorphism. For each $A_{i}$, there is a canonical homomorphism $\beta_{i}:A_{i}\rightarrow A$ between each $A_{i}$ and their direct limit $A$. If my understanding is correct, $\beta_{i}$ need not to be surjective,so I am curious about what are the conditions that makes at least one $\beta_{i}$ surjective?

I am thinking the if each $\alpha_{i}$ are injective, then $\beta_{i}$ may be surjective, but consider a chain of inclusion, each $\alpha_{i}$ are injective but none of the $\beta_{i}$ will be surjective. So I am not sure.